# Wordpress - Creating multiple plugins with same functions etc.?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

i wrote a plugin for wordpress which works well. I use for example something like this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'head_css');
function head_css() {
    $myStyleFile =  plugins_url( 'css/a2m_lp.css', __FILE__ ) ;
    wp_enqueue_style( 'a2m_lp_stylesheet',$myStyleFile,false,'1.0');
}
```

And i use HTML code and JQuery selectors to create some good features as well.

If i create a second plugin that can be installed in the same wordpress environment, i have to rename all HTML/JQuery classes/selectors and have to update all function names in order to have unique names - is that correct? How do i know if anybody else used some of the selectors.

Is there a possibility to use them twice?

Answer (score 1):

I would make your functions anonymous something like this

```
$head_css = function() {
$myStyleFile =  plugins_url( 'css/a2m_lp.css', __FILE__ ) ;
wp_enqueue_style( 'a2m_lp_stylesheet',$myStyleFile,false,'1.0');
}
```

or in order to work with wordpress add_action

```
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
  $myStyleFile =  plugins_url( 'css/a2m_lp.css', __FILE__ ) ;
  return wp_enqueue_style( 'a2m_lp_stylesheet',$myStyleFile,false,'1.0');
});
```

that way you dont waste namespace and conflicts with other plugins

Comment: Thanks. Good idea - but nevertheless i have to alter all html classes etc. if i use them as a selector for jquery, right?

Comment: I just got the idea to create a global variable, which can be used as pre- or postfix for html classes/jquery selectors. Is that a recommend solution?

Comment: yeah you can create a global variable to use as pre/postfix, i am assuming you want to create another css class and add to the ones you have to target those separately in jquery, if not you could also do that

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
if (!function_exists('my_function')) {
    function my_function() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I recommend declaring the function like that for every plugin that uses it - because the plugins may be called in a different/unexpected order in future.

Additionally, if you can set up your development environment efficiently - for example, creating a single file/library that contains the `my_function` code, then importing that into each of your plugin projects - it means you will only have once source file to update with any changes in the future, which could make maintenance a lot easier.